# finding image of the remopte url using preg_split

Tags: php, php4

i want the content inside of the "img" tag from the string.
for ex:- if

```
str="< img src="/files/thumbnails/001.simonhiggins_comm games_thumb.jpg" title="Commonwealth Games" alt="showreel" class="clear-right-margin" />"
```

then i want to o/p using preg_split as follows:-

```
src="/files/thumbnails/001.simonhiggins_comm games_thumb.jpg" title="Commonwealth Games" alt="showreel" class="clear-right-margin"
```

i used following code to find it out

```
$x = preg_split('/<img(.*?)>/',$p,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

but it is not working properly for some cases for ex:- 
if there is a space or a blank line inside the image tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $data, $matches)`

Comment: sorry but it's not working 
my img tag is as follows 

"<img src="/files/thumbnails/001.simonhiggins_comm games_thumb.jpg" title="Commonwealth Games

" alt="showreel" class="clear-right-margin" />
"


and i want something like following.


src="/files/thumbnails/001.simonhiggins_comm games_thumb.jpg" title="Commonwealth Games

" alt="showreel" class="clear-right-margin"

Comment: How about..

`preg_match('/<img(.+?)\/>/', $data, $matches);`